# When settingintegrity levels using icacls command it gives access denied error?

Tags: windows, sandbox, icacls

When I am running following command on windows it says access denied. I am running from admin .

> icacls hello.bat /setintegritylevel high

what needs to be done to get this working.

Comment: Are you running your command shell as admin, or are you just signed into an admin account?

Comment: The run your command shell as admin, otherwise I believe it normally runs with ordinary user rights.

Comment: Yes running command as admin has resolved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to run an application, like `icacls` under administrative privileges, on Windows, starting your command prompt in administrator mode will allow your commands within it to execute with administrative privileges.

Don't be tempted to always run your command prompt in admin mode. For safety, this should always be a conscious decision.